# Corona Admobs Integration

Tags: lua, admob, coronasdk

**-- CODE IN MY build.settings**

```
settings =
{
    orientation =
    {
        default = "landscapeRight",
        supported = { "landscapeLeft", "landscapeRight" },
    },

    android =
    {
        versionCode = "11"
    },

    androidPermissions =
    {
        "android.permission.INTERNET",
        "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
        "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE",
    },

    build =
    {
        neverStripDebugInfo = true
    },

    plugins =
    {
        -- key is the name passed to Lua's 'require()'
        ["CoronaProvider.ads.admob"] =
        {
            -- required
            publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
        },
    },  

}
```

**-- CODE IN MY main.lua**

```
provider = "admob"
appID = "ca-app-pub-XXX/XXX"
AD_TYPE = "interstitial"
```

**-- CODE IN MY HomeScreen.lua**

```
local adsObject = require ("ads")
local toast = require ("toast")

local function adListener( event )
    local msg = event.response
    toast.new("Event Msg: "..msg, 2000)
    print("Message received from the ads library: ", msg)
    local statusText = display.newText( "", 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 22 )
    statusText:setTextColor(153, 0, 51)
    statusText.x, statusText.y = display.contentWidth * 0.5, 160
    if event.isError then
        IS_ADD_INIT = false
        toast.new("--FALSE--", 2000)
        statusText.text = "Error: "..msg;
    else
        toast.new("--TRUE--", 2000)
        IS_ADD_INIT = true
        statusText.text = "Success: "..msg;
        adsObject.show( AD_TYPE , { x=centerX, y=centerY } )
    end
end


function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group=self.view
    if appID then
        adsObject.init( provider, appID, adListener )
    else        
        toast.new("NO APP ID", 2000)
    end
end
```

PLEASE HELP.
I AM NOT ABLE TO LOAD ADS WITH THE ABOVE CODE.

my adListener(event) never gets called.
Please correct me!
Also can i use a global reference of the `adsObject` which i will define in the main.lua

Answer (score 0):

Try after changing the `plugins` table as below:

```
plugins =
  {
    ["CoronaProvider.ads.admob"] = 
                     { 
                       publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
                supportedPlatforms = { ["android"] = true }
             -- supportedPlatforms = { iphone = true, ["iphone-sim"] = true } --for iOS
                     }
  }
```

Keep coding.................... :)

Answer (score 0):

Check This out

```
-- ************* ADMOB *********************
-- Hide the status bar
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

-- The name of the ad provider.
local adNetwork = "admob"

-- Your application ID
local appID = "a1522213c297e5a"

-- Load Corona 'ads' library
local ads = require "ads"

-- Initialize the 'ads' library with the provider you wish to use.
 if appID then
   ads.init( adNetwork, appID )
 end

 -- initial variables
 local sysModel = system.getInfo("model")
 local sysEnv = system.getInfo("environment")
 local bgW, bgH = 320, 480

if appID then
 local adX, adY = display.contentCenterX, 0
 local halfW = display.contentWidth * 0.5
 local font, size = "Helvetica-Bold", 16
 if sysEnv == "simulator" then
     local warningText2 = display.newText( "Please build for device ", adX, adY, font, size )
     local warningText3 = display.newText( "to test this sample code.", adX, adY, font, size )
     warningText2:setTextColor( 255, 255, 255)
     warningText3:setTextColor( 255, 255, 255)
     warningText2:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
     warningText3:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
     warningText2.x, warningText2.y = halfW, 0
      warningText3.x, warningText3.y = halfW, 16
 else
     ads.show( "banner", { x=adX, y=adY} )
 end
else
 -- If no appId is set, show a message on the screen
  local warningText1 = display.newText( "No appID has been set.", 0, 105, font, size )
  warningText1:setTextColor( 255, 255, 255)
  warningText1:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
   warningText1.x = halfW
end
```

And your build.settings is fine.